# Why i cannot get a value from AutoCompleteTextView.Toast didn't show my selected values

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","iPad","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
        AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        actv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: first: use `Log.d`, not `Toast`s, second: call `setOnItemClickListener`, not `setOnItemSelectedListener`